# Determine the number of distinct congruence classes that are contained in the space of all 3x3 real symmetric matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

The question is from chapter 11.7:Approximating Eigenvalues in my textbook and I have attempted the question but there are no answers at the back so I am unsure where to start.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  What do you understand about congruence classes.

Comment: They are called congruent if P^T A P =B so A and B are called congruent if that is true.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia